# Unable to delete only existing row in Matrix field with required columns in Channel Form

Tags: matrix, safecracker, pixelandtonic, delete

I'm using a channel form with inline errors containing matrix fields in EE 2.10.1 with Matrix 2.6.1

The matrix fields are set to have no rows initially & they have some required columns, but the fields themselves are not required.

I've realised that if you have a matrix field with one row & then delete that row, deleting doesn't work. The row does vanish on clicking delete, but when you submit the channel form you get errors for the required columns in the row which has reappeared.

Deleting rows within a multi row matrix does work (even the first row if there are multiple rows). It just seems to be deleting the one & only row left in a matrix field that doesn't work.

Any insights or help on this would be greatly appreciated thanks.